# Calculate the average date difference

Tags: mysql, datediff

This is the essential setup of the table (only the DDL for relevant columns is present). MySQL version 8.0.15

The intent is to show an average of date difference interval between orders.

```
    CREATE TABLE final (
    prim_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    cust_ID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    item_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cust_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (prim_id),
    COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=145699
```

Additional information:

```
cust ID -> cust_name (one-to-many)
cust_ID -> order_ID (one-to-many)
order ID -> item_name (one-to-many)
order ID -> created_at (one-to-one)
prim_id -> *everything* (one-to-many)
```

I've thought of using min(created_at) and max(created_at) but that will exclude all the orders between oldest and newest. I need a more refined solution.

The end result should be like this:

Information about average time intervals between all orders, (not just min and max because there are quite often times, more than two) measured in days, next to a column showing the client's name (cust_name).

Comment: What does the 'final' table represent? orders? I would like to suggest that it might be a bad table name.

Comment: order details, actually. This is by no means normalized, and I don't intend to bother myself normalizing it, since the sole purpose is to produce data I will include in a report I'm working on.
I'm just stuck on this avg(datediff(x,y)) thing
the problem I'm facing is how to define x and y like this:
x - to always be the older (oldest to next-to-newest) date
y - to always be the newer (next-to-oldest to newest) date

and to have the x and y work grouped by the cust_ID (it's actually an email, hence the varchar type for it)

Comment: So why not start with the real order table? I assume it has a 'created_at' field in it. If that's not the case, then can you confirm that there's one, and only one, 'final' record per order?

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is in this one table.
There are multiple rows of the table, per order.
Example: rows 1 and 2 refer to one client, one order, and two items purchased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right you might use a subquery getting the date of the previous order. Use `datediff()` to get the difference between the dates and `avg()` to get the average of that differences.

```
SELECT f1.cust_id,
       avg(datediff(f1.created_at,
                    (SELECT f2.created_at
                            FROM final f2
                            WHERE f2.cust_id = f1.cust_id
                                  AND (f2.created_at < f1.created_at
                                        OR f2.created_at = f1.created_at
                                           AND f2.order_id < f1.order_id)
                            ORDER BY f2.created_at DESC,
                                     f2.order_id DESC
                            LIMIT 1)))
       FROM final f1
       GROUP BY f1.cust_id;
```

---

Edit:

If there can be more rows for one order ID, as KIKO Software mentioned we need to do the `SELECT` from the distinct set of orders like:

```
SELECT f1.cust_id,
       avg(datediff(f1.created_at,
                    (SELECT f2.created_at
                            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT f3.cust_id,
                                                  f3.created_at,
                                                  f3.order_id
                                         FROM final f3) f2
                            WHERE f2.cust_id = f1.cust_id
                                  AND (f2.created_at < f1.created_at
                                        OR f2.created_at = f1.created_at
                                           AND f2.order_id < f1.order_id)
                            ORDER BY f2.created_at DESC,
                                     f2.order_id DESC
                            LIMIT 1)))
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT f3.cust_id,
                             f3.created_at,
                             f3.order_id
                    FROM final f3) f1
       GROUP BY f1.cust_id;
```

This may fail if there can be two rows for an order with different customer IDs or different creation time stamps. But in that case the data is just complete garbage and needs to be corrected before anything else.

---

2nd Edit:

Or alternatively getting the maximum creation timestamp per order if these can differ:

```
SELECT f1.cust_id,
       avg(datediff(f1.created_at,
                    (SELECT f2.created_at
                            FROM (SELECT max(f3.cust_id) cust_id,
                                         max(f3.created_at) created_at,
                                         f3.order_id
                                         FROM final f3
                                         GROUP BY f3.order_id) f2
                            WHERE f2.cust_id = f1.cust_id
                                  AND (f2.created_at < f1.created_at
                                        OR f2.created_at = f1.created_at
                                           AND f2.order_id < f1.order_id)
                            ORDER BY f2.created_at DESC,
                                     f2.order_id DESC
                            LIMIT 1)))
       FROM (SELECT max(f3.cust_id) cust_id,
                    max(f3.created_at) created_at,
                    f3.order_id
                    FROM final f3
                    GROUP BY f3.order_id) f1
       GROUP BY f1.cust_id;
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but Nikola Pavlovic said there could be multiple rows in 'final' per order... bummer. That needs to be resolved first.

Comment: Yes I see. I don't think there will be muliple customers per order, but I bet there will be multiple 'created_at' values. Your subquery could group by 'order_id' and then take the MAX() of the 'created_at' field, to guard against that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: Yes it could. But it also needed an aggregation function around `cust_id` then. But if there are no different customers for an order that is no problem. I edited that alternative into the answer too.

Comment: cust_ID identifies only its' own set of orders, and no other cust_ID can have the same order ID. every order is unique to its' timestamp (30k something customers, 80k something orders and same 80k something different timestamps)

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I'm not convinced this resolves my problem but before I'll commit to that statement, I need to confirm on a few examples from the data itself, to verify that manually. 
The suggestion, from what I understand of it, takes only ONE fresher date than the oldest and fails to account for if a client has say, 10 orders...


Will get back to you once I clear everything up

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner. There was a lot going on. In the end, it was actually min and max what I was looking for, but I accepted the suggested answer since that is the only viable route otherwise.
In all my confusion, I forgot that in math, no matter how many elements (dates) you have in an array (time interval) the average between those elements(dates) can always be calculated by taking the difference between the highest and lowest valued element, divided by total number of elements in the array. It's always the simple, stupid things where I find myself stumbling....

Comment: In any event, thanks for your quick responses, your quick and overly complex responses actually *helped* me remember why I know KISS to be true!!!